# python convert to csv based on document header in python

Tags: python, text, export-to-csv

I have many pdf  documents . Written a python code to extract text from the same. The structure of the document is as follows

Case NO: ABCD

Appellant: XYZ

Hearing dare: 01-01-2222

Facts of case:
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah

Decisions in the case:
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah

I want to convert the text file in to csv as follows:

Case No|Appellant|Hearing Date|Facts of Case|Decision

ABCD   |XYX      |01-01-2222  |Blah Blah    |Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah 
                               Blah Blah     Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah

is it possible using python. The code till now is as follows:

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('1.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pages = int(pdfReader.numPages)

with open("1.txt", "a") as myfile:
    for i in range(pages):
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
            num= pageObj.extractText()
            stg=num.strip()
            print(stg)
            myfile.write(stg)
```

print ('done')e here

Text file is attached herewith. Thanks

Comment: what have you been trying so far ?

Comment: The titles end with " : " . Tried to import  text in to CSV and use Text to Coloumn. Tried also to strip the empty spaces and split using split function. not getting desired results.

Comment: Sample text file is here

Comment: Can you edit your post with sample code and sample text file so we can test it and try to help ?